# OpenFeint Turn-Based Multiplayer

Tags: iphone, multiplayer, openfeint

I'm wondering if anyone has ever used the OpenFeint Turn-Based Multiplayer Framework.  I am trying to open and compile the sample application that comes with that framework and I'm getting errors.  I'm really starting to get the feeling that no one has ever used it before.

I need someone to walk through how to run the Turn-Based multiplayer sample application called MPSampleApp. I opened the MPSampleApp project and then followed all the steps under "Add OpenFeint as individual source files" in the getting started readme file for OpenFient.  I'm running Xcode 4, iOS 4.2, OpenFient 2.9.1, and the Turn-Based Multiplayer framework 1.1.2.

Does anyone even know if this is a valid configuration to be able to open "MPSampleApp"? Please remember that "MPSampleApp" is the sample app that comes with the multiplayer framework, not OpenFeint. If you can confirm that they will work, could you list out for me all of the steps necessary to get the MPSampleApp compiling?
Here is the error I'm getting:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
>
> ```
>   +[ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
> ```
>
> "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
>
> ```
>   +[ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
> ```
>
> "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
>
> ```
>   +[ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
> ```
>
> "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
>
> ```
>   +[ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1):

When building the multiplayer sample with a recent version of OF SDK for iOS (such as version 2.10), please make sure to include Apple's "MobileCoreServices" framework. You may also remove from the sample code any references to the following methods:

[OpenFeint applicationWillResignActive] 
[OpenFeint applicationDidBecomeActive] 
[OpenFeint applicationDidEnterBackground] 
[OpenFeint applicationWillEnterForeground]

These methods were deprecated as of OF 2.8 SDK for iOS, and no longer need to be called from the application delegate. We now internally listen for these events.

-- Joe Sandmeyer 
OpenFeint Integrations

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same exact error while trying to compile the two sample apps provided with the OpenFeint multiplayer SDK.  I was able to solve it and compile after using the solution provide by @Joe :

1. Remove the messages applicationWillResignActive, applicationDidBecomeActive from your app delegate.
2. Make sure to add the MobileCoreServices framework.